# How do I use MLE for non-iid actual data?

Tags: regression, maximum-likelihood, extreme-value

In this [paper](https://sci-hub.se/10.1016/0022-1694(86)90004-1), the author try to fit the Gumbel distribution based on the r largest value of each year using the maximal likelihood estimators: the likelihood function for r largest values $X_{n1},\dots, X_{nr}$ of each year $n=1,\dots, N$.

Since there is a increasing trend of the data (not iid), so we cannot use the likelihood function for iid data.

***Question: How do we deal this case?***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of assuming a fixed $\mu$, the authors use the regression function $\mu(n) = \alpha +\beta n/N$.  So they plug its  RHS into the ikelihood, to replace each $\mu$, and get a model with three unknown parameters $\sigma, \alpha, \beta$. You estimate them the usual way, by maximising the likelihood (2.5) for your data at the design points.  You can use a standard optimisation routine, such as `optim` in R. (Note the need for constraints, such as $\sigma \geq tol > 0$.) Typically, handling a $\log$ likelihood is easier numerically. There is R functionality for the standard Gumbel distribution, which could help with a starting guess in optimisation. There might be a more specific R package for this type of problem.

Comment: I guess the linear regression is a better model for the data trend than a constant $\mu$, yet still simple. Or this could be based on the scientific background to the problem, I dunno. Do they give an explanation?

Comment: You can go more rigorous and compare the two models according to AIC and/or BIC. Either information criterion has a model complexity penalty $=$ the number of model parameters, to reflect the bias-variance trade-off.

Comment: Formally, nothing precludes non-iid likelihood, iid is just a convenience really.

Comment: The distribution is iid around a point $\mu(n) = \alpha +\beta n/N$ assuming a  fixed $n$. Check nonlinear regression via likelihood. The transformation you mention is an alternative way to deal with non-iid, eg heteroscedasticity. It has pros and cons, such as trickier interpretation of the parameter estimates on the transformed scale. So it's problem-dependent. Anyway, it's a big, separate topic.

Comment: Why can't you use a non-iid likelihood? Not illegal. Might be worth trying to really understand the definition of likelihood.

Comment: Hmm. I'm not sure this is a good format for a semester course in statistics. 
It's a linear regression since the function is linear in the parameters. So yes, probably a linear regression book would be enough for a start.

Comment: Right independent good enough for likelihood. Nope, no need for iid. Just treat it as a function to optimise.